# Can I pass a unique_ptr's reference to a function?

Tags: c++

Can I pass a unique_ptr's reference to a function? If not why should I avoid it?

Ex:

```
void func(unique_ptr<Clss>& ref);

main() {
   unique_ptr<Clss> a = std::make_unique<Clss>();
   fn(a);
}
```

Comment: the question is rather unclear. You can ask you compiler if it is possible, and if it is not, then there is no point in avoiding it

Comment: Compiler allows this - but is there any issues which arises upon using it?

Comment: I'd say it depend on the function, really.

Comment: It lets you modify the `unique_ptr` in-place, as expected. The weird thing to do would be to pass it by const-ref which doesn't contribute anything much of value and usually indicates poorly-thought-through design. Both will compile though.

Comment: @Leushenko - On the contrary. Passing by a const-ref is the one that shouldn't raise eyebrows. You let the function refer to the object, even letting it know there's only one owner, without passing ownership. Perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @StoryTeller what does this achieve over passing the pointee by const-ref? The user shouldn't normally need to know how many owners there are if it isn't taking ownership itself, which it can't do through a const-ref to a `unique_ptr`. It's an extra indirection that risks becoming null and not much else.

Comment: a function should only take a smart-pointer as a parameter, if it needs to access/change the ownership. otherwise, take a reference to the pointee.

Comment: Herb Sutter gives a good explanation of different way to pass parameters and how to interpret and choose among them, including using references to smart pointers: https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/

Comment: @Leushenko - Passing by const-ref doesn't encode ownership data (and it's not the same as passing a const ref to a pointer, anyway). And personally, I'd rather not have an innocent call like `fn(a)` result in `a` being empty. Well, not unless I have to do it, and the function has a damn awesome name that doesn't leave room for misunderstandings. I don't like it for the exact same reason you listed. `a` becoming null right under me.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm lost as to the utility of encoding ownership data for an object that you can't share or modify the ownership of. It's a meaningless constraint. `T const &` doesn't become null/invalid during the call unless your preconditions are very broken. It's `unique_ptr<T> const &` that might.

Comment: @Leushenko - We are obviously at an impasse here. I'll just end with saying that my position is also the responsible for why I liked seccpur's answer. The modification to the pointer is not done without the caller knowing. Very important if overloading is brought into the mix. Of course, that can start a whole other discussion.

Answer (score 8):

> Can I pass a unique_ptr's reference to a function?

Yes, a `unique_ptr` is class like any other.

You should do this when you want to mutate an existing `unique_ptr` from a function (e.g. calling `.reset()` on it).

If only you want to access the object inside `unique_ptr<T>`, take `T&` or `const T&` in your function interfaces, so that they can be used independently of `unique_ptr`.

Comment: If function foo accepts T& and you have unique_ptr<T> how do you call function foo? Do you call foo by writing foo(my_unique_ptr_object);

Comment: @catloverxx: `foo(*ptr)`

Answer (score 6):

According to Herb Sutter:

https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/

**Passing unique_ptr by reference is for in/out unique_ptr parameters.**

```
void f( unique_ptr<widget>& ); // (d)
```

This should only be used to accept an in/out `unique_ptr`, when the function is supposed to actually accept an existing `unique_ptr` and potentially modify it to refer to a different object. *It is a bad way to just accept a widget, because it is restricted to a particular lifetime strategy in the caller*.

Thanks @sgvd

Comment: Good that you have added the link, but I would suggest copy more text from the link, since it difficult to understand the context without checking out the link.

Answer (score 3):

See this code snippet, two ways of passing unique_ptr as function parameter. fun1 will take ownership of the object ( hence should be forwarded from the caller) but func2 commits thats the reference unique_ptr object will be passed as reference and will not be modified by the function.

```
void func1(unique_ptr<Clss>&& moved_obj) // this function takes ownership
{
    //do something with the moved_obj

    moved_obj.reset();
}

void func2(const unique_ptr<Clss>& ref_obj) // this function takes reference
{
   unique_ptr<Clss> new_obj = std::make_unique<Clss>(*(ref_obj));
}


int main() {

   unique_ptr<Clss> a = std::make_unique<Clss>();
   func1(std::move(a));

   unique_ptr<Clss> b = std::make_unique<Clss>();
   func2(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Up-voted. Though I must say it feels odd to have to write `std::move` where an object may not be moved. Would have been happier with something like `func1(concede_ownership(p));` but that's neither here nor there, and I'm just rambling.

Comment: Better to have `void func2(const Clss &)` here.

Comment: Shouldn't `func2(a);` be `func2(b);`? Passing the moved-from pointer again is not a good idea.

Comment: @PaulR: Thanks, typos. Edited

Comment: `// this function takes ownership` is incorrect.  A rvalue reference parameter does not mean the function takes ownership, just that it *can* take ownership.  Only if it actually moves the thing it is referring to will ownership actually be transferred.  Otherwise you just have a reference to a unique_ptr like the second function, albeit one that lets you modify that passed object.

Answer (score 2):

I see those valid meaningful signatures:

```
void take_ownership(std::unique_ptr<Clss>);
// or void take_ownership(std::unique_ptr<Clss>&&);

void use(/*const*/ Clss*);
// or void use(/*const*/ Clss&);

std::unique_ptr<Clss> create(/*args..*/);

void might_take_ownership(std::unique_ptr<Clss>&);
```

The later might make sense, but it is more difficult to reason with (as any I/O argument).

If you can, prefer one of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a `std::unique_ptr` to a function is perfectly fine as long as you respect the same rules you would when passing a regular reference to a function:

- the underlying `std::unique_ptr` and the object it points to must live at least as long as the function will use the reference;
- in case of multi-threading, barriers must be put in place.