# Ownership not delegated to a function using unique_ptr < T > && and std::move ( )

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, ownership-semantics

I was reading about passing `unique_ptr` to a function here:

[Can I pass a unique_ptr's reference to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863969/can-i-pass-a-unique-ptrs-reference-to-a-function)

The winner answer tell that this function takes ownership:

```
void func1(unique_ptr<Clss>&& moved_obj) // this function takes ownership
{
    //do something with the moved_obj

    moved_obj.reset();
}
```

I did a small example to understand:

```
// The functions used for that
void pass_unique_by_copy(std::unique_ptr<int> T) { *T = 9; }
void pass_unique_by_ref(std::unique_ptr<int> &T) { *T = 9; }
void pass_unique_by_move(std::unique_ptr<int> &&T) { *T = 9; }

 
 // main code
 std::unique_ptr<int> g = std::make_unique<int>();
 pass_unique_by_copy(std::move(g));
 assert(g == nullptr);
 cout << "The ownership as given\n";
  
 // passed as reference is ok 
 g = std::make_unique<int>();
 pass_unique_by_ref(g);
 assert(g == nullptr);
 cout << "Still the owner\n";
  

 // moved ownership
 pass_unique_by_move(std::move(g));
 assert(g == nullptr);          // --> g is not nullptr , why ?
 cout << "content was moved lost ownership\n";
```

The output should be :

```
The ownership as given
Still the owner
content was moved lost ownership
```

But It's been held on the last `assert`

1- If I am moving the ownership to the function `g` should be `nullptr` after isn't ?

2 - why the guy put a reset inside the function ? I didn't get it  could someone explain me ?

Comment: That answer is incorrect.  A rvalue reference parameter does not mean the function takes ownership.  Only if it actually moves the thing it is referring to will ownership actually be transferred.  Otherwise you just have a reference to a `unique_ptr` like the second function, albeit one that lets you modify that `unique_ptr` object.  I've left a comment on that answer, hopefully the OP will reply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I understood clear this `pass_unique_by_move(std::move(g));`  is equivalent to pass as a reference ? But I am moving something which accepts a rvalue. it makes me more confused.

Comment: `move` doesn't actually *move* anything.  All it does is return a rvalue reference to the passed in object.  To actually move something you need to give it to another object like `foo some_name = std::move(some_object);`  Just doing `foo&& some_name = std::move(some_object);` just makes `some_name` a reference to `some_object`.